# How can I convert a byte[] into ArrayList<CustomObjec>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, arrays

I receive a byte[] from my internal storage and now I don't know how to convert it into my ArrayList.

I'm referring to this post. [-->>THIS<<--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047537/read-an-arraylist-from-internal-storage)

**snipped code:**

```
                ArrayList<KFZInfo> toReturn = null;
                FileInputStream fis;
                try {
                    fis = openFileInput("kfzList");
                    ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                    toReturn = (ArrayList<KFZInfo>) oi.readObject();
                    oi.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

At `toReturn = (ArrayList<KFZInfo>) oi.readObject();` it is throwing an error which says: `java.lang.ClassCastException:  byte[] cannot be cast to java.utio.ArrayList`

**And thats how I write it on the internal storage:**

```
try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("kfzList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    oo.writeObject(listKfzInfo.toString().getBytes());
                    oo.flush();
                    oo.close();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```

}

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: how did you wrote it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
oo.writeObject(listKfzInfo.toString().getBytes());
```

with

```
oo.writeObject(listKfzInfo);
```

I assuming that listKfzInfo is an `ArrayList<KFZInfo>` and that `KFZInfo implements Serializable` and that all fields inside `KFZInfo` implements `Serializable`

Comment: Now the `toReturn` variable from the arrayList is null. Any idea why null?

Comment: was it null when you wrote it?

Comment: it is related to something else in your code. Not with Serialization. By the way: does KFZInfo implements Serializable?

Comment: ohh yeah good boy. I hadn't implement it. thanks a lot. add this to your post pls. I accept it.