# Versioning data schema in android internal storage

Tags: java, android, schema, storage, versioning

I am using Android's internal storage to hold data for my application and I am trying to find a good way to handle reading data of an older schema. For example, let's say I have serialized and written several instances of class Data to a file:

```
public class Data{
    private String text;
    public Data(text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

and later I read that stringified data back out and cast to (Data). But then say I change Data to look like this:

```
public class Data{
    private String name;
    public Data(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

now that the property is named differently, when I read out data that was saved in the original schema, it will not easily cast to the new type. What are some solutions to version the data so that I can read out old data and cast it to a new type?

Comment: this might just be me not knowing about a standard approach but - how did you serialize your data in the first place? ie what format is it stored in?

Comment: say it is using the method found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17047638/3529744