# Save and Get data from ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android

I am using an activity to display the contact list, and inside this activity I have a button to add another contact. I can add a new contact and display it in the listview. But all the contacts will be gone if I exit the app or press the BACK button.

I think I am having a problem while trying to get data from an Internal Storage. I can save the data and I can see the `CONTACT_LIST`s file in the Emulator. But I am not able to read the data from it. I put the "SavingFuction" in "OnPause" and "ReadingFunction" in "OnResume". I am  using below code snippet for saving data:

For Internal storage:

onPause, onResume

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    SavePreferences(arrContacts);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    getContact(arrContacts);
}
```

-Saving:

```
public void SavePreferences(ArrayList<Contacts> ct)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fOS = openFileOutput("CONTACT_LISTs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(fOS);
        oOS.writeObject(ct);
        oOS.flush();
        oOS.close();
        fOS.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

-Reading

```
public void getContact(ArrayList<Contacts> ct)
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fIS = openFileInput("CONTACT_LISTs");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        ct = (ArrayList<Contacts>) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        fIS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

How can I make it right?. Everything's just gone after I closed the app and reopened it.

this is my Contacts.java

```
    public class Contacts implements Serializable
    {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ArrayList<Contacts>contactList=new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        String name;
        String number;
        String address;

    public Contacts(String name, String num, String add)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = num;
        this.address = add;
    }

    public Contacts() {

    }

    public void addContact(Contacts ct)
    {
        int i=0;
        for(; i < contactList.size(); i++)
        {
            Contacts nvOld=contactList.get(i);
            if(nvOld.getNum().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(ct.getNum().trim()))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i < contactList.size())
            contactList.set(i, ct);
        else
            contactList.add(ct);
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String na)
    {
        this.name = na;
    }

    String getNum()
    {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNum(String nu)
    {
        this.number = nu;
    }

    String getAdd()
    {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAdd(String ad)
    {
        this.address = ad;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you update your question with the onResume and onPause  ?

Comment: @gmetax I have updated it. :)

Comment: i answered to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31512644/2401265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.make sure you data object is implements Serializable;

2.make sure data is save OK(you can find this file in explore,Note the file size and time);

3.make sure read data is ok；

At last：

i check this source code,Contacts is not implements Serializable.
this is the reason you are looking for;

you can implement custom class to storage data.

Comment: I have updated the Contacts.java class. I have followed this article to do so far. They can do it but i can't.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047537/read-an-arraylist-from-internal-storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047537/read-an-arraylist-from-internal-storage)

Comment: [https://github.com/tamchau2809/VPhone/tree/master/src/chau/vpphone](https://github.com/tamchau2809/VPhone/tree/master/src/chau/vpphone). Here is my code.. :). I have problem in Contact files..:)

Comment: see  the github.com 's   pull request.

Comment: i had fix the bug,the reason is  code logic error.you do add Contacts finish to return ContactsListActivity, will call getContacts method(At this the time will be null).             my english is poor,see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Working with streams it's not only about catching exceptions but also closing streams. It is a good practice to use following construction:

```
try {
    //read from stream
} catch (Exception e) {
    //work with Exceptions
} finally {
    //close all streams even when exception was called
}
```

Why don't you close fIS in Reading block?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I copied the old code.. :).. I have updated it. I still can't get the data back after closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

as i thought change that

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    SavePreferences(arrContacts);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    getContact(arrContacts);
}

public void getContact(ArrayList<Contacts> ct)
{ 
    try 
    { 
        FileInputStream fIS = openFileInput("CONTACT_LISTs");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        ct = (ArrayList<Contacts>) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        fIS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

to that

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    SavePreferences(arrContacts);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    arrContacts = getContact();
}

public ArrayList<Contacts> getContact()
{ 
    ArrayList<Contacts> ct = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    try 
    { 
        FileInputStream fIS = openFileInput("CONTACT_LISTs");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        ct = (ArrayList<Contacts>) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        fIS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } 
    return ct;
}
```

**another one update**

```
public void getContact()
{ 
    try 
    { 
        FileInputStream fIS = openFileInput("CONTACT_LISTs");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        arrContacts.clear();         
        arrContacts = (ArrayList<Contacts>) oi.readObject();
        contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        oi.close();
        fIS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I still can't get the data.. :).. But thank you for your help

Comment: My listview will be cleared if I use this `ArrayList<Contacts> ct = new ArrayList<Contacts>();`  or maybe I think. Because my List is empty no matter what.. :D.

Comment: yes.. :d.. I upload my code to [https://github.com/tamchau2809/VPhone/tree/master/src/chau/vpphone](https://github.com/tamchau2809/VPhone/tree/master/src/chau/vpphone). You can see my code clearly

Comment: if you add `contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
 `onResume` after `arrContacts=getContact();`   ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ArrayList<Contacts> getContact()
{
    ArrayList<Contacts> ct = null;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fIS = openFileInput("CONTACT_LISTs");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        ct = (ArrayList<Contacts>) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        fIS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage()); 
    }

    return ct;
}
```

i test it, it's work ok.